Ansible AAP: template error while templating string: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.compat.version'
This task is part of a role which decommissions VM's. To test one part of the role separately which is causing an issue, i have put it into a playbook.
The error i get is: "msg": "template error while templating string: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.compat.version'. String: {{ mountfat | community.general.json_query( query ) }}",
Playbook used in AAP:
---
- name: test get instana mounts
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - vmname: vmcode1234
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.setup:
        filter: 'ansible_mounts'
      delegate_to: "{{ vmname }}"
      connection: ssh
      register: mountfat

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mountfat | community.general.json_query( query ) }}"
      vars:
        query: "ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[?contains(mount,'instana')].mount"

mountfat:
{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "ansible_mounts": [
      {
        "mount": "/foo",
        "device": "n/a",
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "options": "n/a",
        "size_total": 37558423552,
        "size_available": 34027737088,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 9169537,
        "block_available": 8307553,
        "block_used": 861984,
        "inode_total": 18348032,
        "inode_available": 18293524,
        "inode_used": 54508,
        "uuid": "n/a"
      },
      {
        "mount": "/foo",
        "device": "n/a",
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "options": "n/a",
        "size_total": 5358223360,
        "size_available": 5286584320,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 1308160,
        "block_available": 1290670,
        "block_used": 17490,
        "inode_total": 2621440,
        "inode_available": 2621418,
        "inode_used": 22,
        "uuid": "n/a"
      },
      {
        "mount": "/foo",
        "device": "n/a",
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "options": "n/a",
        "size_total": 5358223360,
        "size_available": 5276213248,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 1308160,
        "block_available": 1288138,
        "block_used": 20022,
        "inode_total": 2621440,
        "inode_available": 2621365,
        "inode_used": 75,
        "uuid": "n/a"
      },
      {
        "mount": "/foo",
        "device": "n/a",
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "options": "n/a",
        "size_total": 1063256064,
        "size_available": 785780736,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 259584,
        "block_available": 191841,
        "block_used": 67743,
        "inode_total": 524288,
        "inode_available": 523971,
        "inode_used": 317,
        "uuid": "n/a"
      },
      {
        "mount": "/app/instana",
        "device": "n/a",
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "options": "n/a",
        "size_total": 2136997888,
        "size_available": 2088247296,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 521728,
        "block_available": 509826,
        "block_used": 11902,
        "inode_total": 1048576,
        "inode_available": 1048571,
        "inode_used": 5,
        "uuid": "n/a"
      },
      {
        "mount": "/app/instana/metrics",
        "device": "n/a",
        "fstype": "xfs",
        "options": "n/a",
        "size_total": 518684672,
        "size_available": 488591360,
        "block_size": 4096,
        "block_total": 126632,
        "block_available": 119285,
        "block_used": 7347,
        "inode_total": 256000,
        "inode_available": 255997,
        "inode_used": 3,
        "uuid": "n/a"
      }
    ]
  },
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "filter": "ansible_mounts",
      "gather_subset": [
        "all"
      ],
      "gather_timeout": 10,
      "fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
    }
  },
  "_ansible_verbose_override": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false,
  "_ansible_delegated_vars": {
    "ansible_host": "vmcode1234",
    "ansible_port": null,
    "ansible_user": "ansibleuser"
  }
}

The module module_utils is to create plugins, i'm not using this module at all, which makes me believe AAP/podman is maybe using that. Googling on that error did not give me any leads.
What i tried and didn't work:
1 quoted 'qry
2 msg to var
3 set_fact used instead of debug
4 add connection: local, comment connection: ssh; comment connection: local
5
 1:   - debug:
        msg: "{{ mountfat | community.general.json_query( 'query' ) }}"
      vars:
        query: "ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[?contains(mount,'instana')].mount"

 2:   - debug:
        var: "{{ mountfat | community.general.json_query( query ) }}"
      vars:
        query: "ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[?contains(mount,'instana')].mount"

 3:   - set_fact:
        insta_m: "{{ mountfat | community.general.json_query( qry ) }}"
      vars:
        qry: "ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[?contains(mount,'instana')].mount"

      - debug:
          var: "{{ insta_m }}"

 4:   - name: test get instana mounts
        hosts: localhost
        #connection: local
        vars:
          - vmname: vmcode1234
        tasks:
          - ansible.builtin.setup:
              filter: 'ansible_mounts'
            delegate_to: "{{ vmname }}"
            #connection: ssh
            register: mountfat

  5:   - set_fact:
           inst_mounts: "{{ mountfat['ansible_facts']['ansible_mounts']|flatten|map(attribute='mount') }}"
       - error:  "inst_mounts": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f939282bf20>"

Before to try this in AAP, i tested it locally ( in my VM) and this did work. I'm puzzled how to troubleshoot this further.
---
- name: get /app/instana mounts
  hosts: test
  connection: local
  vars:
  #vars_files:
  #  - mountfact.yml
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.setup:
        filter: 'ansible_mounts'
      delegate_to: "vmcode1234"
      connection: ssh
      register: mountfat

    - set_fact:
        inst_m: "{{ mountfat | community.general.json_query( query )  }}"
      vars:
        query: "ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[?contains(mount,'instana')].mount"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inst_m }}" 

output of above and intended required output in AAP:
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vmcode1235] => {
    "msg": [
        "/app/instana",
        "/app/instana/metrics"
    ]
}

Edit: Adding | list to attempt nr 5 seems to help.
5:   - set_fact:
           inst_mounts: "{{ mountfat['ansible_facts']['ansible_mounts']|flatten|map(attribute='mount') | list }}" 


Did you check if the community. general collection is correctly installed in your runner? The error woukd be quite misleading if this is the problem but that's the only thing I can think of at this stage.

Thanks for that. The community.general collection is correctly installed as the other tools from community.general work normally.
What i have been told is that the builtin.setup.filter does not work well with delegate_to.
This is supposed to work without delegate_to. So i need to add a second entry in my site.yml file for my role. I will then need to add the vmname to AAP/inventory before it can be picked up as a var by the site.yml, i believe.
What i gather is that delegate_to is not working as it is intended or the docs do not reflect that or ...

I encountered the same error when the collection community.general was too recent. Installing an older version fixed this error.

Could you edit the answer to be a bit more precise in what software products' versions were relevant and what the version numbers were (versions where a discrepancy caused an error, and versions to which you reverted).?

Unfortunately not. I wiped the whole system and started again from scratch in a more controlled way.
